# Como enviar/encapsular um arquivo em um .apk para usar na instalação do app?

Tags: android, apk, encapsulamento

Tenho um arquivo .xls que gostaria de encapsular junto ao apk para que na hora de instalar o app ele use esse arquivo para popular uma base dados. Como fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode incluir o seu arquivo .xls na pasta `res/raw/`. Existe também no projeto uma pasta `assets/`, e existe pouca diferença entre guardar nela ou na pasta `res/raw/`. Você pode saber um pouco mais e constatar as diferenças entre um e outro [neste link](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#ApplicationProjects) da documentação.